# Prevent calendar notification from interrupting my WP7 app

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a sleep phase alarm clock for Windows Phone, and it's working pretty well by now. First problems with the fact that the app has to be opened the whole time have been overcome by manually "darkening" the screen etc. But there is another problem I stumbled over last night: If the calendar triggers a popup for some notification, my app seems to completely stop running until I click it away, which is of course disastrous for an alarm clock app.

Are there ways to overcome this issue e.g. by disabling notifications as long as this app is running? Or that the app is as well running under the calendar popup?

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is no way to disable system notifications**. And this limitation is there for a good reason. Just imagine the scenario where a user would download and install an app that would suppress meeting announcements and whatnot.

Comment: But why interrupt the running app? Why not just continue it behind the popup?